# How to safely secure AC adapter wire to a skirting and a door frame?

Tags: electrical, wiring, cables, doorbell

I purchased an adapter for my doorbell and need to secure it to skirting and a door frame before it is fed through the door frame to the doorbell outside.

[image]

I thought it would make sense to use a couple flat cable clips like these:

[image]

I don't really like how cable clips look though. My next option was to use one of those cable tackers because staples usually look neater on a skirting board or door frame than cable clips. I have not yet done it this way because I think the staples may be too big for adapter cable.

One last option I had in mind was to extend the adapter cable using thicker electrical wire. I could even use a sleeve on the existing adapter cable, but I can't find white sleeves anywhere.

The doorbell I'm going to install in my home has 2 terminals and after some research, this adapter was recommended by people who have the same doorbell.

As an electrican, how would you go about solving this problem? The door is less than 2.5m away from the plug socket.

Comment: That particular unit is illegal and unsafe, mail order web sites strike again! (Amazon is NOT a safe place to buy electrical gear).   Note the lack of UL listing.  However, 24V plug-in transformers that are UL listed are readily available. They will have terminals to which you attach your own "thermostat" cable.  Do not use the cable that came with this thing, it's cheap garbage.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica that's a 240V-50hz input transformer.  It may be missing the requisite safety testing markings (I don't know what's expected in the UK), but if so UL isn't the one that should be but isn't there.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica This is the first time I'm learning about UL listings. I did some research and the whole thing got me slightly paranoid. For peace of mind, I have returned the adapter in this post, and have ordered the official Ring doorbell plug-in adapter which actually has a thick cable which will play nicely with 10mm cable staples.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Looks perfectly fine if OP is located in Germany -- the CE mark is all that's needed.

Comment: @arne No. CE is the most widely faked mark in the world.  EU enforcement can't reach fakers who are (and keep their assets) outside the EU, and the fakers know it. Amazon is mostly 3rd party sellers, and it is a haven for fakers, since it allows them to project sales into the EU while keeping their boots in China where they are untouchable. CE is a garbage mark, EXCEPT a) inside a reputable bricks-and-mortar store inside the EU, or b) sold by a manufacturer based inside the EU and shipped from *their own* warehouse (at that point it's fine if it was made overseas).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica That might all be true, but you still don't need an UL listing on this thing for it to be "street legal" in the EU. So your statement about the missing UL listing making this device in any way "illegal" is highly location-specific.

Comment: @arne Well, I think people understand that.  The foreign countries have their own domestic independent third party Recognized Tesiting Labs, such as TUV for Germany, and thanks to GATT they all interchange.  The takeaway is that "cheap cheese from overseas" is not safe.

Answer (score 5):

I would fish it through the walls.  If I had an unfinished basement I'd use an outlet there and feed it up the outside wall through its sill plate.

If the question is how to most attractively surface mount wire like this: there are very small cable staples.  There are ones painted white.  I'd use tiny white cable staples.  There are tiny versions of the one in your picture, including white-headed nails.   There are "bell wire staples", and there are white ones.  There are tiny round staples meant for staple guns for just this purpose.  Alarm companies used them a lot before ZWave.

Look for "low voltage staple gun", low voltage staples, fire wire staples, Cat5 staples, etc .... they will all work, just pick one that you like the look of.

Comment: "fish it through walls" good luck with English construction...

Comment: @SolarMike ah, well spotted.  As the English say, very well spotted indeed.  Ok so I would hammer a channel through the centuries-old brick wall for this.  :). Ok, I wouldn't do that.  I'd surface mount.   And I may as well say it for you .... OP probably doesn't have a basement.

Comment: As a side note, those little white low-voltage wire staples also come in brown in case your trim happens to be brown. I still have a few wires stapled up to the walls in various places in my house. There weren't staple guns for these when I installed them...

Answer (score 5):

I have done what both of the answers have suggested, it just depends on the individual case. Using the staples though, always leaves dings where I've hit the wall or baseboards/trim, etc.  In many cases I've used super glue gel and just glued the wire to the wall, top of baseboard or corner of door frame. This is a permanent install because if you try to remove the wiring, there's a chance of tearing the insulation off the wires but it works really well. It's a fast install, a thin strip of glue, press down the wire and it is done.

Comment: And the glue can pull the paint off... done that as well :)

Comment: I like this one.  The glue pulling the paint off is only a problem until the next time you paint the room ... at which time the wires will be *under* the paint. And without staples, it might even look like a millwork detail. :)

Comment: I've used small dabs from hot glue gun and pushed the wire into it as it cools. To remove apply some isopropyl alcohol to soften the glue

Answer (score 4):

I would remove the architrave and skirting and hide the wire - much neater.

As for extending that cable, the joint will be behind skirting or architrave so soldered or chocolate block will both work. Colour won't be a relevant issue as my way the cable is hidden.

Comment: Just don't drive a finish nail through the freshly installed cable when you're putting the trim back up!

Comment: @FreeMan Done that! :) then learnt to think where the nails will go...